# Ionic / angulfire2 - Query join reference multiple times

Tags: ionic2, angularfire

I'm building app with Ionic and angulfire2 and I'm trying to join multiple references from firebase by using the object key.

Database looks following:

```
{
  "achievements" : {
    "200" : {
      "authorId" : "nGSlhjaDRKh8XdrgxcusU0wdiHN2",
      "description" : "I did it"
    }
  },
  "challengeAchievements" : {
    "100" : {
      "200" : true
    }
  },
  "challenges" : {
    "100" : {
      "name" : "test challenge"
    },
    "101" : {
      "name" : "test challenge 2"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "nGSlhjaDRKh8XdrgxcusU0wdiHN2" : {
      "email" : "user1@test.com"
    },
    "wBMX8WOHIpM7dEkzj0hM19OPMbs1" : {
      "email" : "user2@test.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to join all this data together so that from challenges you get achievements, and from achievements you get the user data.

Currently I'm able to get the achievement details, but not the user data. My provider looks like this at the moment:

```
  getChallengeAchievements(challengeKey) {
    return this.rtdb.list(`/challengeAchievements/${challengeKey}`)
      .map(achievements => achievements.map((achievement) => {
        if (achievement.key)
          achievement.details = this.getAchievementDetails(achievement.key);

          achievement.user = this.getAchievementUserDetails(achievement.details.authorId);

          return achievement;
      }));
  }

  getAchievementDetails(achievementKey?: string): Observable<any> {
    if (achievementKey)
      return this.rtdb.object(`/achievements/${achievementKey}`);
  }

  getAchievementUserDetails(authorId?: string): Observable<any> {
    if (authorId)
      return this.rtdb.object(`/users/${authorId}`);

    else console.log('Not found');
  }
```

How should I structure the authorId query in this function? If I use static value in

```
achievement.details.authorId('nGSlhjaDRKh8XdrgxcusU0wdiHN2')
```

I'm able to receive the data.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by subscribing to the first join "achievement.details" and obtaining the user data from there.

```
  getChallengeAchievements(challengeKey) {
return this.rtdb.list(`/challengeAchievements/${challengeKey}`)
  .map(achievements => achievements.map((achievement) => {

    if (achievement.key)
      achievement.details = this.getAchievementDetails(achievement.key);

      achievement.details.subscribe(
        details => {
          achievement.user = this.getAchievementUserDetails(details.authorId);
      })

      return achievement;
  }));
```

}